# Cannot convert String to date in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, date, oracle11g

I'm trying to insert Date into table from user input but something doesn't work.

I have the following Query :

```
    INSERT INTO DOCTORS.TREATMENTS 
    (START_OF_TREATMENT, END_OF_TREATMENT, DOCTORS_ID,PACIENTS_ID, DIAGNOSIS_ID) 
    VALUES (TO_DATE(&startdate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), TO_DATE(&enddate, 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 3, 1, 1);
```

For start date I set :

> 2000/10/01

And for end date I set :

> 2000/11/01

It seem ok for me but I've got the following error :

> Error report -
>   ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
>   ORA-06512: at "SYS.STANDARD", line 167
>   ORA-06512: at line 2
>   01858. 00000 -  "a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected"
>   *Cause:    The input data to be converted using a date format model was
>              incorrect.  The input data did not contain a number where a number was
>              required by the format model.
>   *Action:   Fix the input data or the date format model to make sure the
>              elements match in number and type.  Then retry the operation.

Any one can explain to me why this error occurred.

Best regards,
Petar.

Comment: The both field's type are Date.

Comment: `2000/10/01 == 200`

Comment: Are you sure THAT is the error message you get? I tried exactly that expression (without the missing single-quotes, see Bob's answer) and I get a different error message, ORA-01840, *Input value not long enough for date format.* And indeed, that is the message I expected, because - as @Bohemian says - Oracle will first substitute the number 200 for the expression you gave it. Bob gave you the right way to correct your code, but why you got the error YOU did is still unclear.

Comment: I'm sure. I receive ORA-01840 but that was when I tried to give date like this 1/1/2005. When I fix the query as Bob's suggestion it works perfect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of the first parameter passed to TO_DATE must be a string. After substitution with the value you've given your code will look like

```
TO_DATE(2000/10/01, 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

which fails as shown.

The solution is to put the parameter usage in single-quotes to make the substituted value a string, as in

```
TO_DATE('&startdate', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

This way, when `&startdate` is substituted you'll get

```
TO_DATE('2000/10/01', 'yyyy/mm/dd')
```

which will work as expected.

Do the same for `&enddate`.

Best of luck.

Comment: It doesn't fall "as shown" (at least on my machine). On my system I get a different error message if the substitution variable is not enclosed in single quotes - see Comment under the original post. While this is the right way to fix the code, it doesn't fully explain why the OP got the specific error message he did.